# How to force X server to 'reopen' input devices

Tags: xorg, touch-screen

I've got a problem with my xorg-server configuration (xorg 1.20.4, locally built).
I've got inputs manually configured including a touchscreen (evdev), and I have AutoAddDevices turned off. (there are problems with other components that forced this approach).

The problem is that when the touchscreen disconnects and reconnects, xorg still has the old /dev/input/event# open, which means that I no longer get touchscreen events.

I want a way to force xorg-server to drop it's current input configuration and reload it on demand WITHOUT restarting the X server.

Comment: You might have to reconsider the AutoAddDevices options, what was the problem you were trying to solve by turning it off?

Comment: We don't use AutoAddDevices because the Xorg server we've built is too new for some of the other components, and we ended up with AutoAddDevices giving us NO input devices. If I can work around this issue for now, I can get on with the 'upgrade to a newer distribution' project and make the whole mess go away, but I need something to give people for the 6+ months that'll take.